# Dominated convergence theorem on a subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, where the dominating function is not integrable on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I shall state the dominated convergence theorem:

> $\textbf{Dominated convergence theorem: }$Let $f_k:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of integrable functions. Suppose there is a positively integrable function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to[0,\infty]$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and all $k$ we have $|f_k(x)|\leq g(x)$.
>
> If $f_k\to f$ pointwise, then $f$ is integrable too and $$\lim_k\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f_k \ d\lambda = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f\ d\lambda.$$

We define a (postive) function to be integrable if $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f\ d\lambda<\infty.$$

$\textbf{Question}$: Suppose I am integrating over some subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. And suppose there is a sequence $f_k:A\to \mathbb{C}$ such that for all $x\in A$ and all $k$ we have $|f_k(x)|\leq g(x)$ for some integrable function $g:A\to \mathbb{C}$.

$\textbf{But}$: suppose $g$ is $\textit{only}$ integrable on $A$, and not on $\mathbb{R}^n$. That is

$$\int_A g\ d\lambda<\infty \ \text{but $\textbf{not}$} \ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g\ d\lambda < \infty.$$

Does the dominated convergence theorem still hold here?

Comment: What is an interval in $\mathbb R^n$ when $n>1$?

Comment: It should be that a function is integrable if $\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f| d\lambda < \infty$

Comment: Sorry, I mean subset. I will edit it.

Comment: @CalvinKhor for the Lebesgue integral, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}fd\lambda<\infty$ iff $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f|d\lambda<\infty$. But yes, I have added that in this definition, $f$ needs to be positive.

Comment: No, because the collection of symbols ‘$\int f d\mu$’ has no meaning prior to defining what it means to be integrable, and further what’s wrong with integrating -1 on $\mathbb R$ to get $-\infty$? Just stick with the standard definitions

Comment: These are the standard definitions. Note that $f$ is positive.

Comment: @PaleBlueDot Still no, in fact I'm not sure why you bothered to define the integrability of positive functions. Your question is about functions $f_k$ taking values in $\mathbb C$. (NB you write $f_k \to f$, am I to assume $f>0$...?) The definition of integrability of such functions is nowhere to be seen. Not that I would have included it, but I wouldnt have bothered to define integrating positive functions either.

Comment: @CalvinKhor it is standard to define Lebesgue integrability first for postive functions, and to then expand it to any function by $f = f_+-f_-$. Then $|f|=f_+ +f_-$, for which the Lebesgue integral is defined. Complex functions are integrable when the real and complex parts are. There really needn't be a discussion about this.

Comment: I know the definition, but I am suggesting you make your question better by including the correct and relevant definition in the question, or to remove the definition and point to wiki maybe,  or the mention of complex valued functions. The definition of the integrability of positive functions doesn't add to the question. As it stands, its like you defined what addition was, and then asked a question about subtraction. There doesn't need to be this discussion, but one small comment and another later...

Comment: @CalvinKhor The reason I added the definition of integrability was to stress that the integration over the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$ needs to be finite, which was why I was unsure of my question because there are functions that are integrable over some subsets $A$, but not over the whole space. But I can appreciate now that by defining the function to be zero outside of $A$ solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming that $A$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb R^{n}$.  Just define $f_k(x)=g(x)=0$ for $x \notin A$ and apply DCT.

Comment: I thought so too. Would you consider my counterexample?

Comment: Sorry, your example doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you :) I went a bit too fast.